# ¿Puedo obtener los datos de la sección red de chrome, desde javascript?

Tags: javascript

quiero aclarar que esto es por curiosidad y aprendizaje. Tengo una página web que hace una solicitud get a un video m3u8 para poder reproducirlo. Al inspeccionar la página y irme a red, aparece la solicitud de url y varias cosas más. Me interesa saber si puedo obtener esa url desde javascript con solicitudes o otra manera.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Ummm cuando hablas de datos de la seccion de chrome te refieres a cosas como cookies o local storage o session storage?, a que te refieres especificamente?, poner un ejemplo de codigo ayudaria que en este caso la pregunta sea mas valedera para la comunidad

Comment: cuando inspecciono una página en chrome, aparecen varias secciones como: elementos, consola, fuentes, red y varias más. En la sección red hay datos que quisiera obtener de una página, es posible mediante javascript?